# Is it good for applying connection pool on both application and proxy tier?

Tags: galera, proxysql

I'm having a Galera Mysql cluster and ProxySQL on top of this cluster. ProxySQL has connection pool mechanism itself.

My question is, should I apply connection pool on application (.net, springboot,...) along with ProxySQL's connection pool ? And what is the recommendation for this ?

Thank you.

Comment: `<opinion>`Connection pools are not of much net benefit`</opinion>`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your application architecture (monolith or Microservices) and the number of databases servers you have. From my experience you don't need too.

ProxySQL opens a pool of connections to the backend servers. It is not 1-to-1 mapping, by default it tries to reuse one backend connection for as many frontend connections as possible. This is called connection multiplexing.

ProxySQL can handle N frontend connections and M backend connections, where N > M (even N thousands times bigger than M).

You can refer to [this old conversation by ProxySQL creator](https://groups.google.com/g/proxysql/c/H8thSBqHANA?pli=1) or its [documentation on multiplexing.](https://proxysql.com/documentation/Multiplexing/)

Also, check out this article on [connection handling & throttling with ProxySQL](https://severalnines.com/blog/connection-handling-throttling-proxysql/). (Disclosure: I am affiliated with this site.)

Comment: Both of your recent answers have links to severalnines.com/blog with `?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=community-engagement` in the URL parameters. Are you affiliated with this site?

Comment: Yes i am @tripleee, hope no issues?

Comment: Any affiliation must be explicitly stated. Please review the [promotion policy.](/help/promotion)

Comment: Thank you very much @tripleee, I see you helped me fix it. I also reviewed the promotion policy. Thank you.